# Roots of serie $\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{a_i + b_i \log(c_i - x)}{c_i - x}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms, roots

I encountered the following serie during an optimization problem:

$\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{a_i + b_i \log(c_i - x)}{c_i - x}$

I need to find the roots of that serie, but I cannot find the way to find a closed-form expression for x. I don't even know if it is possible. What method would you use to approach this problem?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I would probably differentiate this function to see if there is any critical point first of all. And seeing if there's a solution for some trivial values like all coefficients are one then extending results.

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jrlllrgbx6 , here check this @joapuipe

Comment: That does seem to indicate convergence to a root. A general form involving variables seems to be doubtful. But if you give them values, then numerical methods can be used.